# Change background Color of a div once you click an li item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need your expertise and help again, What i'm trying to do is when you click the List item below it will get the background color from the span and apply/change the color on the main div every time the user clicks on the list item

Note: the list item is not only two item it can be more.

**HTML:**

```
    <li class="variable-item color-variable-item" title="Black" data-value="black">
        <span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-color" style="background-color:#000000;"></span>
   </li>
    <li class="variable-item color-variable-ite" title="Red" data-value="red">
        <span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-color" style="background-color:#dd3333;"></span>
    </li>
```

Main HTML that will change the background color once you've click the list item

```
<div class="slick-list"></div>
```

**JS that i got**

```
$("li.variable-item.color-variable-item span").each(function(index, value) {
  var colorjg = $( this ).css( "background-color" );
  $(".slick-list.draggable").css('background-color', colorjg);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `click` function to check which `li` > `span` was clicked and get its `color` and apply that color to your `div`

This will work with multiple `li's` if you have them (I have added few different `li` with different color for `demo` purposes)

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(".variable-item > span").click(function() {
  var colorjg = $(this).css("background-color"); //get the bg color
  $(".slick-list").css('background-color', colorjg); //apply the bg color
});
```

```css
li span {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="variable-item color-variable-item" title="Black" data-value="black">
  <span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-color" style="background-color:blue;">Click me</span>
</li>
<li class="variable-item color-variable-ite" title="Red" data-value="red">
  <span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-color" style="background-color:yellow;">Click me</span>
</li>
<li class="variable-item color-variable-ite" title="Red" data-value="red">
  <span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-color" style="background-color:red;">Click me</span>
</li>
<li class="variable-item color-variable-ite" title="Red" data-value="red">
  <span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-color" style="background-color:green;">Click me</span>
</li>

<br>
<br>
<div class="slick-list">dsds</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

js:

```
    let liEl = document.querySelectorAll('.variable-item');
    let divEl = document.querySelector(.slick-list'');
    liEl.forEach((el) => {
      el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        divEl.classList.add('redBg');
      });
    });
```

css:

```
.redBg{
background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution could be to surround the section you want to change in a .Using a JS event, you can write a function that will be executed every time your  is clicked on. Here is a link going into more detail about the "onclick" event. I want to emphasize "onclick" executes a function, so make sure to use parentheses when calling the function by name (ex: myFunction()).